# .map rendering empty list (just the bulletpoint)

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Hoping somebody can help me with this issue I am having. Basically, I am creating a budget app. You enter your budget, item name and cost and submit it. It will then print it at the bottom of the app (different component) and i will do some calculations for remaining budget etc.

I am currently stuck on passing the values from my stateful component in to my functional component. I have successfully managed to pass in the data through props and iterate through them. However, instead of outputting the data i require in li format, it just outputs the li bullet points. If I change the returned output to text it does render the text (console.log also works)  in li format, but for some reason if I am trying to output the props it wont.

Any help is appreciated.

```
 class FormInput extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { budget: 0, items: [] };
  }

  handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const item = [
      { name: event.target.itemName.value, price: event.target.itemCost.value },
    ];
    const budget = { budget: event.target.budget.value };
    this.setState({ budget, items: [...this.state.items, ...item] });

  };

 const Cost = (props) => {
  const test = props.item.map((ite, index) => (
    <li key={index}> {ite.item} </li>
  ));
  return (
    <div>
      <Container
        style={{
          alignitems: "center",
          textAlign: "left",
          fontWeight: "bold",
          color: "black",
        }}
      >
        <Card>
          <Card.Body>
            {" "}
            <ul> {test} </ul>{" "}
          </Card.Body>
        </Card>
      </Container>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using the `map` function, your item object will be directly returned, no need to add `.item` :

```
const test = props.item.map((item, index) => (
   <li key={index}> {item.name} - {item.price} </li>
));
```

You array objects do not have an `item` property.

Comment: This works. Thanks very much! I used ite as a placeholder as  I was not sure if using item would mess it up but I can see now that it does not. Cheers!